# Permalink is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a page that is for a blog and what is meant to happen is that when you click on the 'read more' or blog title then it will open that blog in the separate page to read. However when I click these two things I get the following message:

> Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving
>   mywebsite/wordpress/?p=20. It may be down for maintenance or
>   configured incorrectly. Here are some suggestions: Reload this web
>   page later. HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected
>   condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil
>   the request.

here is the code:

```
<div class="box">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <article>
            <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <h7>BY LOUIS MOORE ON</h7> <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time><?php the_content(); ?>
<a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"/><h8>READ MORE</a></h8>  </br>   
</br><div class="h9"></div>
</article></br></br></br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try remove `esc_url`...
besides move `</h8>` inside  the `a` tag

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h8>READ MORE</h8></a>
```

**UPDATE**

Lets debug, put this in your wp-config:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true); // creates and update wp-content/debug.log
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

to get error info in the screen, this is a development stage, right?

Comment: @louismoore18 it is online to check it closer? the problem seems exists in the target page, not in the permalink. can you see the server error_log? there you have all info you need to catch the bug...

Comment: @NimikOS Got the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /customers/d/b/a/louismoore.net/httpd.www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/single.php on line 37

Comment: yipi! so go single.php and look closer, start removing that ` '/'`